# Trying to update a Unity Dropdown list with c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the Unity UI dropdown option but I'm not sure how to keep it updated. This way works but I feel like it shouldn't be clearing and re-adding every update like this. Is there a better way of doing so?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ChangeDropdown : MonoBehaviour
{

public UnityEngine.UI.Dropdown dropdown;
public List<string> changes = new List<string> ();

private int counter;

void Start ()
{
    dropdown.AddOptions (changes);
}

void Update ()
{
    dropdown.ClearOptions ();
    dropdown.AddOptions (changes);
}

public void addToChanges(string changed){
    changes.Add (changed);
}

public void addToDropdown(){
    addToChanges ("Test " + counter.ToString());
    counter++;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this?

```
public void addToDropdown(){

    string text = "Test " + counter.ToString();
    addToChanges(text);
    dropdown.options.Add(Dropdown.OptionData(text));
    counter++;
}
```